# how to listen event through router-outlet?

Tags: angular, events, router, eventemitter, router-outlet

I need the parent component listen a event emitted in the child componente. Like this:

parent component:

```
<router-outlet (finalizarManifestacao)='avancar()'></router-outlet>
```

child component:

```
@Output() finalizarManifestacao = new EventEmitter<any>();

finalizar(manifestacaoIdentificada: boolean) {
        this.finalizarManifestacao.emit();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot emit events through the `router-outlet`. You need to create a global service and emit events to the service that your parent component can then watch for those events.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can create a service to share data between two or more components.

You will need a variable of type as subjectsBehavior where you can change the value with variable.next(true/false) from child component.

On the other hand subscribe it with as variable.asObservable().subscribe(value  => avancar()) to listen changes from parent component.

Here you can check how to add and use a service: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4